# R troubleshoot script, why NULL

Tags: r

I try to process big file to get serial of total by offset position, all individual pieces work OK, but then I need to write result into file, for this exercise to get more skills I try first to put all of them into `df` and this doesn't work, I get NULL or other Error, what is wrong, please check my code. 
I tried to use `df[nrow(df) + 1,] = list( "x")`

```
#  z <- readLines("C:\\RRR\\CA_Mild1.txt",warn=FALSE)
z <- c("A111111111111110111111711111111111", "B222222222222222222222222222222222")
z    # test sum by offset = OK
cat("F1:  ", format(sum(as.numeric(sub(' ','0',(sub(' ','0',substr(z,5,6)))))),big.mark=","))
cat("F2:  ", format(sum(as.numeric(sub(' ','0',(sub(' ','0',substr(z,15,17)))))),big.mark=","))
cat("F3:  ", format(sum(as.numeric(sub(' ','0',(sub(' ','0',substr(z,22,24)))))),big.mark=","))


     # trying now to write all results to df  and/or write to file        ERROR !!!
df <- data.frame(Value=character())    # create new df
df
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = list ( cat("F1:  ", format(sum(as.numeric(sub(' ','0',(sub(' ','0',substr(z,5,6)))))),big.mark=",")) )
```

even when I try to store single result in var  I'm getting NULL

```
a <- cat("F1:  ", format(sum(as.numeric(sub(' ','0',(sub(' ','0',substr(z,5,6)))))),big.mark=","))
a
> a <- cat("F1:  ", format(sum(as.numeric(sub(' ','0',(sub(' ','0',substr(z,5,6)))))),big.mark=","))
F1:   33
> a
NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes will fix your code, I believe.

First, instead of `cat` use `paste0`. I'm not too familiar with `cat`, but `paste0` will connect your strings together if that's what you want. Until I make that switch I get an error that the `replacement has length 0`.

Second, add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you create your data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(Value=character(), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Until I do that, I get a second error, `invalid factor level, NA generated`. Which makes sense, because `Value` is by default a factor, and it has no levels!

---

To find the `cat` / `paste0` issue, I thought I'd look closer at what it was you were trying to add to the data frame. I looked at your final line and ran this:

```r
class(
  cat(
    "F1:  ",
    format(
      sum(as.numeric(sub(' ','0',(sub(' ','0',substr(z,5,6)))))),
      big.mark=","
    )
  )
)
```

You get a really weird response:

```
F1:   33[1] "NULL"
```

When we do the same thing with `paste0` instead of `cat`, it's much simpler:

```
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Sure, sorry didn't know V check = Accepted